# Is $S\smallsetminus T = \lbrace z \in S : z\not\in T \rbrace$ an open set, a closed set or neither?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $S$ and $T$ are two sets of complex numbers such that $S$ is open and $T$ is closed. Define a new set $$S\smallsetminus T = \lbrace z \in S : z\not\in T \rbrace$$

Is $S\smallsetminus T$ an open set, a closed set, or neither?

I have the intuition that the set $S\smallsetminus T$ is open, but I don't know how to justify it. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**

$$S\setminus T=S\cap T^c$$